# PHP returning %u05D0

Tags: php, encoding

I have a variable in php and the value is in another language:

```
שלום לכולם
```

when I try to get the value back it returns this:

```
%u05D0%u05D9%u05EA%u05D9
```

if I set the variable value in english it returns the intended value just fine, but in any other language it will return some weird combination similar to that. can somebody help me? thanks

this is the code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
sleep(0.1);
$myfile = fopen('names.txt','a');
fwrite($myfile, $_COOKIE['output']. "\n");
fclose($myfile);
$_COOKIE['output']=null;
```

}

the variable is output

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: I edited it and I showed you the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those characters are in Unicode and in cookies those are typically stored as encoded one way or another. Usually url-encoded.

For encoding presented in question you may decode it that way:

```
$encoded = "%u05D0%u05D9%u05EA%u05D9";
$decoded = json_decode("\"".str_replace('%',"\\",$encoded)."\"");
echo $decoded; // should show איתי
```